# VSPackage control added/removed to Visual Studio designer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

When the control is added or removed in the design time of VS, I guess there should be an event generated which can be used to control the behavior VS after the event.

I was searching for an Interface in VSSDK which tells you when a control is added/removed on the Visual Studio design surface or (asp.net control in design/source page). Is there such an event?

Thanks!